# Knowing the polygon id and getting the extent

Tags: arcgis-server, polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a text box where I have the polygon Id like, `"id_of_the_polygon_12345"`. Is it possible to get its extent and zoom onto it? I have figured out how to do it upon clicking on the map. But could not figure how to do the same knowing my poly Id.

Comment: create a query task to return geometry.On task success complete, set map extent to the geometry.You will find more help on this link http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/querytask.html  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a QueryTask and obtained the geometry of the feature. I then assigned the feature extent to the map extent so that it appears zoomed.

```
function searchGeometry(polyId){
    //building a  query
    queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("URL_OF_THE_SERVICE");
    //build query filter
    query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.where = "UNIQPOLYID = '" + polyId + "'";
    queryTask.execute(query, queryResults);
}
function queryResults(featureSet){  
    var resultSet = featureSet.features;
    var geom = resultSet[0].geometry;
    //Convert the geographic geometry to WebMercator Geometry so that it can be set to my map.
    var shape = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(geom);
    //check if geometry is polygon
        if(shape.type==='polygon'){
            //get extent
            var featureExtent=shape.getExtent();
            //now zoom to this extent           
                map.setExtent(featureExtent);
        }else{
            //not a polygon         
            alert("Shape you selected is not a polygon");
        }
}
```